# constexpr lambda / ‘x’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘x’?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I am experimenting with C++17's constexpr lambdas to get compile time strings:

```
#include <utility>

template <char...>
struct str
{
  constexpr auto operator==(const str&) const { return true; }
  void foo() const;
};

template <typename S, std::size_t... Ns>
constexpr auto make_str(S s, std::index_sequence<Ns...>)
{
  return str<s()[Ns]...>{};
}

#define LIT(s) \
  make_str([]() { return s; }, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(s) - 1>{})

constexpr auto x = LIT("hansi");
constexpr auto y = x;
static_assert(x == y);
```

Looks good so far. But then I tried calling a member function:

```
x.foo();
```

Using the current gcc from trunk (g++ (GCC) 7.0.0 20161102), I get the following error message:

```
c.cpp:19:1: error: ‘x’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘x’?
 x.foo();
```

See https://godbolt.org/g/uN25e1 for a demo

Since I am not even trying to use `x` as a type, this strikes me as weird.

Is that a compiler bug? Or is `x` something really strange?

Comment: Can you link to a demo? https://godbolt.org/g/lWExfT Seems to work

Comment: @themagicalyang Just add the `x.foo()`. Adding the demo link.

Comment: `x.foo()` was added. You need to call `x.foo()` inside main. @Rumburak

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Your code has a hidden bug, since `sizeof(s)` can either yield the size of a pointer or the size of `char[N]`. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243ef48a3f1db5cc)

Comment: @ClaasBontus I don't think so. Since the lambda does not capture anything, `s` has to be a string literal for the code to work, doesn't it? I might be able to provide a nicer error message, though.

Comment: @ClaasBontus no, `sizeof` is called on the string literal, it will yield the size of the array. There's no decaying going on.

Comment: @krzaq I am afraid you are wrong. See this [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/eNVaWh)

Comment: @ClaasBontus but you're calling `LIT` on a pointer in your example. In the question OP clearly uses the string literal directly

Comment: @krzaq Right. The example works. All I wanted to say is that the macro will not work in all cases one might naively expect.

Comment: @ClaasBontus In your example, I wonder why `s` is known in the lambda? Shouldn't this require a capture?

Comment: @Rumburak Good point. Somebody else might tell us, if this is a bug in gcc.

Comment: @Rumburak, `s` has static storage duration. There's no need to capture it. Captures are for `this` and local, automatic storage duration variables that are ODR-used.

Comment: @chris it's a non-static local object inside `main` function.

Comment: Filed [a question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40406560/3876684).

Comment: You should close this question as the problem is that you're just calling a function at namespace scope, so it's basically a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by others, this is just a result of calling a function namespace scope.

IMHO, the error message is quite obscure, though.