# Can sizeof be applied inside a lambda on a variable that is not captured or is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a follow up of the discussion [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40374191/3876684).

The following code compiles both under gcc and clang ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2046196d29616a91)). This is surprising for the case in line `//1` since the lambda does not capture anything. For the case of `MCR2`, where the lambda returns the pointer itself, we get the expected compile time error (line `// Will not compile`). How is application of operator `sizeof` different from returning the pointer?

```
#include <iostream>

#define MCR1(s) \
  ([]() { return sizeof(s); })()

#define MCR2(s) \
  ([]() { return s; })()

int main() {
  auto *s= "hello world";

  auto x1 = MCR1( s ); //1
  auto y1 = MCR1( "hello world" );
//  auto x2= MCR2( s ); // Will not compile
  auto y2= MCR2( "hello world" );

  std::cout << x1  << "  " << y1  << '\n';
  std::cout // << x2 << "  " 
            << y2 << '\n';
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Following up on the discussion here is another example. Surprisingly, the line marked `//2` now compiles under gcc7 (development version) ([live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lNHiunRlgH0qVOnu)). The difference here is that expressions are marked `constexpr`, now.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MCR1(s) \
  ([]() { return sizeof(s); })()

#define MCR2(s) \
  ([]() { return s; })()

int main() {
  auto constexpr *s= "hello world";

  auto constexpr x1= MCR1( s );
  auto constexpr y1= MCR1( "hello world" );
  auto constexpr x2= MCR2( s );             //2
  auto constexpr y2= MCR2( "hello world" );

  std::cout << x1 << "  " << y1 << '\n';
  std::cout << x2 << "  " << y2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Isn't the situation in your original example https://godbolt.org/g/eNVaWh even more astonishing? There you return s in a lambda and it still compiles.

Comment: @Rumburak You are right again. Added another example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambdas can "see" a *lot* of things in their surrounding scope without needing to capture them:

-- Global variables:

```
int x = 42;
int main() { []{ std::cout << x; }(); }
```

-- Static local variables:

```
int main() {
    static int x = 42;
    constexpr int y = 1337;
    []{ std::cout << x << y; }();
}
```

-- Functions:

```
int x() { return 42; }
int main() { []{ std::cout << x(); }(); }
```

-- Types:

```
using x = std::integral_constant<int, 42>;
int main() { []{ std::cout << x::value; }(); }
```

-- Local variables used in unevaluated contexts:

```
int main() {
    int x = 42;
    []{ std::cout << sizeof(x); }();
}
```

This just naturally falls out of the language rules. You can do the same thing in C++98 with a hand-written callable object:

```
int main() {
    int x = 42;
    struct functor {
        int operator()() const { return sizeof(x); }
    };
    std::cout << functor{}();
}
```

It's unsurprising, as `sizeof` does not evaluate its expression:

```
int main() {
    int x; // uninitialized
    using y = std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof(x)>; // x used in a constant expression

    using z = std::integral_constant<size_t, 4>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<y, z>::value, "");

    std::cout << y::value;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference is the (lack of) evaluation of context. `sizeof` is unevaluated.

As per N3337 (≈C++11)

> §5.1 2 [expr.prim.lambda] / 11
>
> If a *lambda-expression* has an associated *capture-default* and its
>   *compound-statement* odr-uses `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration and the odr-used entity is not explicitly captured,
>   then the odr-used entity is said to be *implicitly captured*;

and

> §5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] / 12
>
> If a *lambda-expression* odr-uses `this` or a variable with automatic
>   storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be
>   captured by the `lambda-expression`. If a *lambda-expression* captures
>   an entity and that entity is not defined or captured in the
>   immediately enclosing lambda expression or function, the program is
>   ill-formed.

ODR use means use in potentially evaluated context:

> §3.2 [basic.def.odr] / 2
>
> An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated
>   operand or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name appears as a
>   potentially-evaluated expression is *odr-used* unless it is an object
>   that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression
>   and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied

Since `sizeof` isn't, and `s` is in *reaching scope* of the lambda expression, it is okay. Returning `s` means evaluating it, though, and that's why it's ill-formed.

Comment: The second quote is irrelevant - that's for attempting to capturing something that can't be captured. You want the sentence immediately before that.

Comment: Thx. Remains the question where this is useful. It obviously leads to surprises.

Comment: @ClaasBontus So far we have one anecdote where it is "surprising". I'd be more surprised if lambda syntax didn't allow it. First of all, it'd be make it plenty broken, to the point of being useless for many common uses.